# Removing object from the list

Tags: javascript

I have this list of objects:

```
mylistobjects = [{id: 1, name: 'One'}, {id: 2, name: 'Two'}, {id: 3, name: 'Three'}, {id: 4, name: 'Four'}, {id: 5, name: 'Five'}]
```

How can I find and remove object from the list by its `id` ?

Comment: use `filter()` to filter out elements from it .... or iterate and remove elements from existing array using `splice()`

Comment: By filtering the array with a condition where the `id` of the element is one you want to keep.

Comment: @PranavCBalan Filter **can** be used here, but there are more simple ways to do this (for loop and find id)

Comment: The dupe target can be found as the second result in Google when searching “javascript remove object by property”.

Comment: @yummypasta Why is that simpler? After you find the ID, how are you planning to remove it? How could it be simpler than `mylistobjects.filter(obj => obj.id !== badId)`?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722159/javascript-how-to-filter-object-array-based-on-attributes.

Comment: @yummypasta :  not just find, he wants to remove it ..... even I'd added both ways in my comment

Comment: By the way, in JavaScript lists are called "arrays".